# Find references Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a massive Visual Studio Solution with many many projects contained within.

The solution uses the SparkView engine and I need to update the reference to a more modern version.

I went through and updated the reference, however something somewhere is still targeting the old dll. It appears in the object browser twice as version 1.1(old) and 1.6(new).

Is there any where to find out all the places a dll is referenced?

Comment: I found a neat plugin on the gallery called "Assembly Version Manager" http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/baa11829-8471-4201-b45a-8afe7c30545d which allowed me to track down all the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a neat plugin on the gallery called "Assembly Version Manager" visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/… which allowed me to track down all the references

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head why not do a 'find in files' text search with a text editor to search the text source files for the old reference?

Comment: I've tried that, however I can see references inside compiled files inside projects (obj directory) that don't contain a reference to the dll I'm searching for, which I fail to fully understand